# Where can I find the WordPress index.php file?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

SO,
It has been a few hours since I enqueued one custom script and one style sheet to my WordPress website functions. Enqueuing, those two worked perfectly; however, Chrome and Mozilla developer tools threw syntax error for my script. Below is the script.

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Here is how I enqueued the script to my WordPress website functions.

```
function enqueue_my_custom_script() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-js', 'path-to-the-file', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_custom_script' );
```

And lastly, here is the syntax error that Google and Mozilla Developer tools throw.

> (index):160 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Now, I have a series of questions.

1. Why the script is not removed when I removed the queueing code from WordPress functions? I still see the script on page source code even after removing the function. (I see the JS file is not embedded in my website, but I see the actual script on my homepage. )
2. Is it wrong to include `<script></script>` tags in a JS file for wordpress?
3. The Google developer and Mozilla both indicates the code is on index.php, but I couldn't find it anywhere on my theme as it has multiple homepages templates. Where could this file be located?
4. the fourth one and the most important of all, how can I get rid of this error and the script?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is probably cache. Clear it and you should be fine.
2. Not only for WordPress, but in general within *.js* file. One would use `<script></script>` tags to either include *.js* file or write js code between the tags. In the last option, you specify that this is javascript code, and should be handled as one.
3. index.php is simply a gateway into your Wordpress site. So all errors will show it being related to index.php in the error trace.
4. Remove script tags from your *.js* file

Comment: Thank you for mentioning cache's problem. Nope, I tried to clear it several times opened the website in incognito mode but no luck.

Comment: @ArashBarez Do you have any cache plugins on WordPress? They can help you clean WordPress cache. It is separate from browser cache

Comment: No, I don't any cache plugin but WordPress itself has a feature to erase the cache. meanwhile FYI the script comes in between <head></head> tags.

Comment: @ArashBarez You should use that feature and try again, to see if the new code is reflected in the result. The script included there is completely normal.

Comment: i tried it way too many times but with no luck. completely lost...

Comment: @ArashBarez Can you install a new plugin for cache? Something like [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/). Try it, and tell if it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You don't include `<script></script>` tags in JavaScript files. `<script>` is a HTML tag, your JavaScript file is not a HTML file.